# Compare the MAE Vs R^2 output for Machine learning 10-fold CV

Tags: statistics

I am comparing two 10-fold cv machine learning outputs. I got:

For model 1:

```
MAE= 0.252
R^2= 0.447
RMSE= 0.37
```

For Model 2:

```
MAE= 0.434
R^2= 0.768
RMSE= 1.164
```

My question is: Is it possible to get higher $R^2$ for higher MAE? What does this mean?

Comment: Higher $R^2$ but also higher $(R)MSE$? Something isn’t right. $R^2=1-\frac{nMSE}{TSS}$, and the $TSS$ term depends only on the data, not the model. // Higher $R^2$ but also higher $MAE$ is perfectly within the realm of mathematical possibilities, however. One has to do with square loss, the other to do with absolute loss. If both loss functions have the same information, there wouldn’t be any reason to use one over the other! (When one prefers each is a topic for another question...or a master’s degree in statistics.)

Comment: it is not MSE, It is MAE

Comment: I meant the RMSE (and therefore the MSE).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about the scenario when the data is following the assumption of linearity.

But let's say the data has non-linearity, then this situation is possible considering the fact that *squares of bigger values can easily cover-up the absolute sum of too many smaller values.*

Let's see this plot below -

*If we move from purple to the red line, MAE will shoot-up since we have too many points with increased MAE but SSE might come down because larger errors have been corrected. SSE coming down will improve the* **R<sup>2</sup>Score.**

$\hspace{3cm}$[image]

This was a rough calculation to get the intuition. You may extrapolate it.

Comment: +1 but this still does not explain how the $SSE$ (thus the $MSE$, thus the $RMSE$) can increase while the $R^2$ increases, too. I do not follow how that happened in the original post.

Comment: Oh, I just focussed on the last line of the question. Yeah, something is abnormal with the result. I Will update/remove my answer accordingly.

Comment: I think your answer is helpful, but the posted numbers are impossible, so I have to wonder what's going on.

Comment: I should mention that the number of data in each model different I have 1677 data for model 1 whereas, 105433 data in model 2